Push Notification delivery failure with SNS and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) endpoint
I'm testing the delivery failure rates of SNS with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) endpoint. Initially, I put the app in the background and sent 10 notifications. Although SNS acknowledged all 10 notifications, my app only received 2. When the app was in the foreground, it missed 1 notification. Additionally, the notifications were received out of order.
Does anyone have insights into these issues?
This is the script for sending notifications:
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

def send_message_to_endpoint(endpoint_arn, message):
    response = sns_client.publish(
        TargetArn=endpoint_arn,
        Message=json.dumps(message),  # Stringify the message here
        MessageStructure='json'
    )
    return response

def send_multiple_notifications(endpoint_arn, start_id, num_notifications):
    for i in range(num_notifications):
        current_timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +00:00")
        message = {
            "GCM": json.dumps({
                "data": {
                    "sentAt": current_timestamp,
                    "userId": 10,
                    "orgId": 1,
                    "notificationType": "ACCESS_CHANGE_NOTIF",
                    "notificationId": start_id + i
                }
            })
        }
        response = send_message_to_endpoint(endpoint_arn, message)
        print(f"Notification {start_id + i} sent: {response}")

endpoint_arn = "application arn"
send_multiple_notifications(endpoint_arn, start_id=80, num_notifications=10)

